# Mongodb access in mocha test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, webdriver-io

So I would like to cleanup my db (before or) after some unit testing.

Basically the code you will see in my codeblocks is in the `afterAll` block from mocha. I am using webdriver.io testrunner for running my tests.

What I don't understand is, how to use db stuff from outside the connect scope, see:

```
function createConnection(){
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:24001/meteor', function(err, db) {
    if (err)
      throw err;
    console.log("connected to the mongoDB !");

    let myCollection = db.collection('test_collection');
    // do stuff with myCollection

  });
}
```

I would prefer, if possible, something like this:

```
function createConnection(){
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:24001/meteor', function(err, db){
    if (err)
      throw err;
  }
}

function getCollection(name){
  return db.collection(name) //don't have db at this scope, problem?
}

//app.js
createConnection();
let myCollection = getCollection('data');
...//do stuff with myCollection

closeConnection();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to access real database?

Comment: yes mongodb 2.6.7, or how can i understand your question?

Comment: That's a bad idea. You always mock database for your tests. The same applies to http requests. Look at something like https://github.com/williamkapke/mongo-mock and use it instead of real database.

Comment: @lukaleli I disagree. If you should mock databases or http requests depends on what you want to test. Performance or load tests for example don't make much sense if you mock all http requests. If my goal is to test a unit - yes you mock the database and http requests because you want to test the unit isolated and want the test to run very fast to enable it to run every time the application is built. If my goal is to test the entire system then working with a test database is fine.

Comment: @Rhayene I completely agree. I thought that OP was talking about unit tests.

Comment: @lukaleli see my comment on your answer

Comment: yeah, now I know :) sorry for confusion. that wasn't intended.

Comment: np i appreciate the hint for the possibility to mock the db

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a MongoDB database in the way you describe, you can use JavaScript promises to make sure you have `db` defined when you call `getCollection`. The code that you would include in your `afterAll` block would then be something like the following:

```js
function createConnection(connection) {
  // return a promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:24001/meteor', function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        // rejects with error if connection fails
        reject(err);
      }
      // returns handle to database if connection successful
      resolve(db);
    });
  });
}

// function takes handle to database and collection name
function getCollection(db, name) {
  return db.collection(name);
}

// test it works
createConnection().then((db) => {
  let myCollection = getCollection(db, 'foo');
  // do stuff with one collection
  // e.g. myCollection.deleteOne({ foo: 1 });
  // ...

  // do stuff with another collection
  myCollection = getCollection(db, 'bar');
  // e.g. myCollection.insert({ bar: 1 });
  // ...

// ensure you catch any errors and log them to the console  
}).catch(console.error);
```

Note that I used a bit of ES6 syntax out of habit, but it works exactly the same with ES5.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is that you always mock things like databases or http requests in your test cases. Take a look at something like [mongo-mock](https://github.com/williamkapke/mongo-mock) and use it instead.

Comment: For unit tests i agree with this statement but for my end2end tests i would like to access a real database (at least for now)

Comment: Btw. afaics my question would also apply to the mongo-mock db as well